# Create line chart with one line for every variable name in row

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

First of all, please excuse my phrasing of this question, having a bit of trouble finding the right words and expressions.

I do have an file that looks like this:

```
Group  Date        y
A      2017-01-01  12345
B      2017-01-01  23456
C      2017-01-01  34567
A      2017-01-02  19876
B      2017-01-02  21987
C      2017-01-02  32145
[...]
```

How can I make a line chart that has one line for every group (3 lines), Date is the x-axis and y is the y-axis?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the display of your Data

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful to get the column-setup. However the datafile will be to big and changing to do this manually. I found an solution by pivot-table that I will present as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found an solution with help from a colleague to transform the rows to columns according to yass' answer.

Create an pivot-table with Date in Columns, Group in rows and Y in Values.

Then select the pivot-table and create line chart.